# Limited tapes-version TM for pair sum

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, turing-machines, linear-complexity, tape-complexity

In the problem of pair-sum we are given a multiset $A$ and a number $\alpha$. We are asked to find whether there is a pair ($2$ numbers) of $A$ s.t. their sum is $\alpha$. Here all numbers are small/constant, $O(1)$, sum of $2$ small numbers requires $O(1)$ actions and their size is $O(1)$ bits for representation.

I'd like to analyse an efficient algorithm for this. The algorithm sorts $A$ and then iterates over the endpoints. If their sum is less than $\alpha$, we will check the second smallest element and the largest. If their sum is larger, we will check the smallest and the second largest. So on and on.

This algorithm takes $O(n\log n)$ due to sorting. However, trying to write it as a single-work tape TM, I'm having trouble. Assuming we have $2$ tapes: one read only tape for the input, and another read/write for the working process.

Sorting the array and writing it on the TM takes $O(n\log n) $ by merge sort, using a single tape. However, what about the process itself of comparison?

If we had $2$ tapes, or a single tape with $2$ access heads, we could have done trivially in $O(n)$. But having a single tape seems to be problematic, as I might run back and forth many times, and running back and forth might take $O(n)$.

My question follows: is there a way to implement this algorithm, or any other algorithm for pair-sum, such that it will need $O(n\cdot \log n)$ runtime, on a TM with $2$ tapes: the first is read only and the second is read-write?

Comment: "their size is $O(1)$ bits for representation.". That implies all numbers in $A$ are smaller than a constant $c$. This implies there is a simple $O(n)$ algorithm using one read-only one tape.

Comment: In fact, with reasonable assumption on the representation of $\alpha$, there is a definitive finite automaton that solves the problem.

Comment: @JohnL. perhaps you could give me a hint? My problem with my $n \cdot  \log n$ algorithm was that the I'll need to move along the work-tape many times back and forth, when in an algorithm I'd simply say "go there" in $O(1)$.

Comment: Are you sure that sorting $A$ costs $O(n \cdot log\ n)$? Are you considering the cost of "going back and forth"?

Comment: Assuming each value comes from a constant range, say $[0,...,c-1]$, we can perform a sort of a count sort. We know the value range ahead of time, and we declare the bits $i\cdot \log n , ...., (i+1) \cdot \log n -1$ to be used by the value $i$. It will represent a counter that indicates how many of $A$'s cells have the value $i$, and therefore it needs $\log n$ bits. Now, we iterate over the read-only tape. Whenever we see a certain value, we go to the corresponding $i$'s cells and

Comment: then increase the number there by $1$. Going to that cell requires at most $c \cdot \log n$ moves which is within $O(\log n)$. Increasing the value is also $O(\log n )$. This is performed for each value in $A$. Therefore, $O(n \cdot \log n)$.

Comment: Is $c$ fixed, that is can I assume that this value is built into the TM?

Comment: Yes, we may assume $c$ is known ahead of time.

Comment: If needed, I don't mind crediting the bounty again, even if the time frame passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: There is no need to sort the given numbers since whether there are two numbers in $A$ such that their sum is $\alpha$ depends on the *set* of numbers in $A$.
Since the choices for the set of numbers in $A$ is $O(1)$, there is an $O(n)$-time algorithm/TM with one read-only tape.

---

Assume that multiset $A$ and a number $\alpha$ are given as $c_{a_i}\square c_{a_2}\square\cdots\square c_{a_m}\square' c_{\alpha}$ as input on the tape, where

- $c_{a_i}$ stands for the cells that represent $a_i$, the $i$-th number in $A$  as a binary number.
- $c_{\alpha}$ stands for the cells that represent $\alpha$ as a binary number.
- $\square$ and $\square'$ are two field separators (neither of them appear in $c_*$).

Since "their size is $O(1)$ bits for representation", there is a constant $c\in \mathbb N$ such that each number in $A$ uses at most $c$ cells, i.e., $a_i\in [2^c] = \{0,...,2^c−1\}$.

Let us specify Turing machine (TM) $M$ as follows.

Given the input as described above, TM $M$ will,
    for each number $x\in[2^c]$:
        check whether $x$ is in $A$. If yes, for each number $y\in \{x+1, x+2, \cdots, 2^c-1\}$:
            check whether $y$ is in $A$. If yes, check whether $x+y=\alpha$. If still yes, halt and accept.
    for each number $x\in[2^c]$:
        check whether $x$ appears in $A$ at least twice. If yes, check whether $2x=\alpha$. If still yes, halt and accept.
    Halt and reject.

Since $c$ is a constant, we can hardcode all "for" loops, $x$, $y$, the result of each check, $x+y$, $2x$, etc. using states and state transitions of $M$. There is no need to alter any tape cell.

Each "check" above involves moving the head of $M$ from the start of the input to the end of the input, and then back to the start of the input, which takes $O(n)$ time. The total running time of $M$ is no more than $2^c2^c2O(n) + 2\cdot2^cO(n)$, which is $O(n)$ still.

We can improve the algorithm/$M$ so that it could run faster with less states. However, that is another task.

Comment: That's a nice way to approach this! It reminds me a bit of count-sort. If we would know that all the values are from a range $1,...,m$, where $m$ is no longer a constant, we would then need to attempt a sorting-like approach?

Comment: I am not sure what might be the fastest approach.